# How to cancel the execution of postDelayed()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an app where some sort of widgets are created on the fly and can be re-arranged with drag and drop. I'm trying to implement 2 things:

1. Long press to initiate drag and drop
2. short press(or click) to open a menu to change some settings.

But i'm having a problem where I can't cancel the code in handler's postdelayed() function. I'm using the following code to make it happen.

```
      _sliders_item[_sliders_counter].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Handler hndlr = new Handler();
                Runnable _run = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        _t1.setText("executed");
                        _t1.show();
                    }
                };
                if (_enable_editor) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        hndlr.postDelayed(_run,1000);
                        //return true;
                    }
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        _t1.setText("menu");
                        _t1.show();
                        hndlr.removeCallbacks(_run);
                        //return true;
                    }
                }
                return _enable_editor;
            }
        });
```

But the problem is, When I long press the object, it works fine. I can initiate the drag and drop. But when I short press it, The code for ACTION_UP event executes but the code inside the runnable still executes. How can I cancel the runnable code when I short press the object?

Answer (score 4):

You have to keep references to your `Runnables` and `Handler` and use `Handler#removeCallbacks()`.

So basically:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() { /* does something */
h.postDelayed(r, 1000);

// When you want to cancel.
h.removeCallbacks(r);
```

Comment: That's what I did. Read the question again... It's not working.

Comment: You're creating a new Handler and a new Runnable each time.  You need to keep the reference to both. Read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `Runnable` outside of `onTouch` event, like seperate method in your Class. Then when you want to actually execute runnable, call your method.

**Quick'n'Dirty Example:**

```
onTouch(..) {
  if (eventDown) {
     // start Runnable
  }

  if (eventUp) {
    // Do not call runnable
  }

}

private void executeMyRunnable( /* Any arguments you need in Runnable */) {
   // Your runnable code here
}
```

Comment: I can't do that. My app creates multiple identical objects that are added dynamically. and the code inside runnable has to specific to a particular object.

Comment: But your dynamic objects, must have some identification. So you cannot pass that parameter to runnable method? That way you would know which object is being currently ran.

Comment: For your runnable, what you need from your TouchListener is the reference to the VIEW object. You can pass that object into your Runnable method when you want to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for long press by taking the time difference between system time at action.down and system time at action.up. If the difference is greater than say 5000 milliseconds, then do the runnable code else the dialog code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`