# How to stop post delayed runnable when menu button pressed.

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a situation where i used post delayed method to set text color when i press menu button right after clicking on button the pending runnable still works when i reopen app.

```
case R.id.pg14_21: {

            clearcolor();

            if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
                mp1.stop();
            }
            try {
                if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 0 && selectlongaudio.GetPreferencesInteger("long", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 0) {
                    pg14_21a.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    media("q1p14_21l.mp3");
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pg14_21a.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                            pg14_21b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

                        }
                    }, 10);
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pg14_21a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            pg14_21b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            pg14_21c.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));


                        }
                    }, 2800);
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pg14_21a.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                            pg14_21b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                            pg14_21c.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        }
                    }, 4800);

                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pg14_21a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            pg14_21b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            pg14_21c.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    }, 10000);
```

}break;}

this is the post delayed runnable code

Comment: Please don't do that. Use an animation to manage how the colour should change. I have made a quick search so I'm not sure this result is 100% relevant but [at least have a look at it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46574186/1827254)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel the execution of postDelayed()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237445/how-to-cancel-the-execution-of-postdelayed)

Comment: @Eselfar brother how will i manage the milliseconds for each textview while audio is playing

Comment: If you want the animation to start when audio is playing, just start it as the same time as the audio. Have a look at the [Property Animation API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) as I think it's the best option to solve your problem